# split delimited row into multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I hope you can give me some guidance.
I have this first table with two comma delimited cells:
[image]
=>I separated the delimited values of the last column with power query. Split rows and remove the pivot (https://exceloffthegrid.com/power-query-split-delimited-cells-into-rows/):
[image]
=>My question is for the second column, how can I avoid that it generates the matrix product and only put a single value in the cell?
I want to get the table like this:
[image]

Comment: This is a simple PowerQuery task where you can select these two columns and split to new rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could add 2 more steps:

Between first and second table above you may create and process a new column with combined values „d-1, e-2, f-3“ and “y-4, x-5” before unpivot.

After unpivot split the columns with the combined values to 2 columns back.